# How to solve the error UnboundLocalError: local variable 'max_contour' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, opencv

Hello everyone I hope you are doing well
I have implemented the following code.
Here is my dataset https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ARQLty-f7i_W6fvvcIx-3VUUzjb3o1KX?usp=sharing

I read the dicom files from the folder and apply some preprocessing to it to the segment area. I have developed a function that segment the area, but I am getting the following error where
I got the following error when I run the code

How can I solve that

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'max_contour' referenced before assignment
```

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pydicom
import numpy
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
import os
import numpy as np
import pydicom as dcm
import cv2
def window_image(img, window_center,window_width, intercept, slope, rescale=True):
    img = (img*slope +intercept) #for translation adjustments given in the dicom file. 
    img_min = window_center - window_width//2 #minimum HU level
    img_max = window_center + window_width//2 #maximum HU level
    img[img<img_min] = img_min #set img_min for all HU levels less than minimum HU level
    img[img>img_max] = img_max #set img_max for all HU levels higher than maximum HU level
    if rescale: 
     img = (img - img_min) / (img_max - img_min)*255.0 
    return img

def preprocess_dicom(img,outdir,image_path):
    ht, wd = img.shape[:2]

    # convert to grayscale
    #gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # threshold
    thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

    # get external contours
    contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    #contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
    
    max_aspect=0
    for cntr in contours:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)
        aspect = w/h
        if aspect > max_aspect:
            max_aspect = aspect
            max_contour = cntr
    
    # create mask from max_contour
    mask = np.zeros((ht,wd), dtype=np.uint8)
    mask = cv2.drawContours(mask, [max_contour], 0, (255), -1)

    # dilate mask
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3,3))
    mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)

    # invert mask
    mask = 255 - mask

    # mask out region in input
    result = img.copy()
    result = cv2.bitwise_and(result, result, mask=mask)

    # save resulting image
     # Open the outlined image
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
    ax[0].imshow(img,'gray');
    ax[1].imshow(result,'gray');
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(outdir,os.path.basename(image_path).replace(".dcm", "_segment.png")), result)
    return result  

def get_first_of_dicom_field_as_int(x):
    #get x[0] as in int is x is a 'pydicom.multival.MultiValue', otherwise get int(x)
    if type(x) == dcm.multival.MultiValue: return int(x[0])
    else: return int(x)
    
def get_windowing(data):
    dicom_fields = [data[('0028','1050')].value, #window center
                    data[('0028','1051')].value, #window width
                    data[('0028','1052')].value, #intercept
                    data[('0028','1053')].value] #slope
    return [get_first_of_dicom_field_as_int(x) for x in dicom_fields]






root=tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()

currdir=os.getcwd()
PathDicom=filedialog.askdirectory(parent=root,initialdir=currdir,title='Please select a folder with DICOM')

if len (PathDicom)>0:
    print(("You chose %s")%PathDicom)
    
lstFilesDCM=[]
for dirName,subdirList,fileList in os.walk(PathDicom):
    for filename in fileList:
        if ".dcm" in filename.lower():
            lstFilesDCM.append(os.path.join(dirName,filename))
RefDs=pydicom.dcmread(lstFilesDCM[0])
ConstPixelDims=(int(RefDs.Rows),int(RefDs.Columns),len(lstFilesDCM))
cal=RefDs.RescaleIntercept
ArrayDicom=numpy.zeros(ConstPixelDims,dtype=RefDs.pixel_array.dtype)
ind = 0 
folder_name=r'C:\Users\Hammad\Desktop'
for i in lstFilesDCM:
    for j in range(1, len(lstFilesDCM)):
        ds=pydicom.dcmread(i)
        ArrayDicom[:,:,lstFilesDCM.index(i)]=ds.pixel_array
        
        window_center , window_width, intercept, slope = get_windowing(ds)
        output = window_image(ArrayDicom[:,:,j], window_center, window_width, intercept, slope)
        imshow(output,cmap='gray')
        output = output - np.min(output)
        output = output / np.max(output)
        output = (output * 255).astype(np.uint8)
        imgsegment=preprocess_dicom(output,r'C:\Users\Hammad\Desktop\manifest-1643119746471\manifest-1645243048125\CPTAC-SAR',i)
        RefDs.PixelData = imgsegment.tobytes()
        RefDs.save_as( folder_name+ '/{0}.dcm'.format(ind))    
        ind = ind+1
```

Can anybody please help me in this

Comment: The error message is pretty self explanatory. `max_contour` is being used before being assigned a value anywhere.

Comment: @Mark what you say its not working.

Answer (score 0):

`max_contour` seems to be getting defined first within the for loop, but you're using it outside the for loop (`mask = cv2.drawContours(mask, [max_contour], 0, (255), -1)`). Try defining `max_contour` near `max_aspect`, which is also accessible to the line with the mask.

```
max_aspect = 0
max_contour = 0
```

Edit: The issue is that `max_contour` is only updated if and only if a contour exists in the list of contours (the variable `contours`). So the default value for `max_contour` will not be accepted by `drawContours` since it's expecting a non-empty contour (hence the `(-215:Assertion failed) npoints > 0` error you encountered).

The solution would be to only create a mask if a contour is found. If not, we could return the original image since there's no mask to apply.

So the code would look something like this:

```
max_contour = []  # Let's initialize to a list instead of 0 since I think that would make more sense. This has no effect on the code itself.
max_aspect = 0
for cntr in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)
    aspect = w/h
    if aspect > max_aspect:
        max_aspect = aspect
        max_contour = cntr

if contours: # This checks if the list of contours is not empty. You could also do `if max_contour:` since that should be satisfied if `max_contour` is non-empty.
    # create mask from max_contour
    mask = np.zeros((ht,wd), dtype=np.uint8)
    ...   # The rest of the code until `return result`
    return result
else:
    return img   # return the original image if the list of contours is empty
```

Comment: when i modified the code like above it gives the error                                                      
                                                                                                                                            
 mask = cv2.drawContours(mask, [max_contour], 0, (255), -1)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-q3d_8t8e\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\drawing.cpp:2501: error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints > 0 in function 'cv::drawContours'

Comment: My bad. The problem is that the code never reaches the if condition inside the for loop. So the variable is still its initial value. I'd recommend creating the mask only if max_contour is redefined. So basically, add `if contours:` right above `# create mask from max_contour` and indent the rest of the function underneath it. You could also add an `else: return img` at the end to return the original image if a contour is not found.

Comment: Can you please modified and share it here, i don't understand your point

Comment: @Aitech Done. Let me know if there are any other issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
for cntr in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)
    aspect = w/h
    if aspect > max_aspect:
        max_aspect = aspect
        max_contour = cntr
```

This the only place in the code where `max_contour` is defined.  So, if you're getting that error, it must mean that the line of code `max_contour = cntr` was never executed.

This would be caused by `contours` being empty, or `aspect > max_aspect` always being false.

Comment: Then How can i solve this?

Comment: @Aitech Assign `max_contour` to some initial value before this loop.

Comment: its not working.